# Mixing WCF bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, session-state, wcf-binding

We have a stateless WCF service, that currently exposes a wsHttpBinding binding, hosted in IIS, and is used by several consumers (web sites and Biztalk).

Unfortunately, this service was extended with functionality that used some kind of internal 'toolkit' which relies on HttpSession. This toolkit keeps quite some data in session. Now the suggestion was made to add a new binding that would allow session, like:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="serviceName">
           <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" />
      </binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>
```

I'm just wondering whether and how this would impact the other consumers or the WCF service? Introducing session means probably an impact on memory usage in the application pool? Can anyone explain the consequences/side effects of this?

Comment: thought this might be of help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13028717/wcf-is-slow-when-reliable-session-is-on-and-with-burst-async-request